# Where can I see why a MySql query stays in loop

Tags: mysql, cpu, cpu-usage

I have a problem and is that I have 8 cores and after a day of doing the same querys, 5 of them stay in 100% and don't decrease.

I changed some part of the code, for example instead of doing `conection.open()`, I use `using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection()){ ... }`, but that doesn't changed something significant.

Reading some blogs and documentation, I think that the problem could be the querys I'm doing, that stay in loop somewhere and that causes the 5 cores in 100%. I have to restart them to have again 0%.

So, my question is, where or how can I see the querys that causes my problem? Do you need to see some querys I use for my application? I'm using `Visual Studio 2022` for code, `phpMyAdmin` as database

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Querys example:

Query 1: Select some records of One Orden

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.Order , p.Delivery, p.Rowing, e.Path, e.Fecha, t.numTram_tr, t.name_tr,
    t.lastname_tr, t.sex_tr, t.document_tr, t.ejem_tr, t.Delivery_tr,
    t.Birthday_tr, t.fechaEmision_tr, t.cod_tr, t.ImgFrenteDni_tr, t.ImgDorsoDni_tr
from Order p
INNER JOIN Delivery e ON p.Delivery= e.Delivery
left JOIN transport t ON p.Delivery=  t.Delivery_tr
WHERE p.Order = '972022'
```

[image]

Query 2: Brings Deliverys in a certain date range

```
SELECT e.Entrega, p.Pedido, p.Remito, e.Fecha
from Entrega e
INNER JOIN Pedido p ON e.Entrega = p.Entrega
WHERE e.Fecha BETWEEN '" + fromDate + " 00:00:00' AND 'toDate 24:00:00'
GROUP BY e.Delivery, p.Order, p.Rowing
ORDER BY e.date ASC
```

[image]

This two querys are the most used. I use indexes for Table Delivery (example query one, e.Delivery is indexed), and all "Delivery" columns are  PK

Also, I'm using `DataTables`, but I didn't download it, I'm refering to the page, in the `<head>` I have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">
```

Comment: Know that phpMyAdmin (PMA) is NOT a database. Unless you have any loops involved in the query, it's more likely a long-running query that may never resolve, or it might, but could take hours depending on the query. Since no SQL was provided, we really have no way to help, without any details about indexes or keys, or the SQL statement itself. Try running the queries directly from the SQL shell or the PMA to see what might be happening.

Comment: `SHOW PROCESSLIST` is one place to start. [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) also helps provide insight.

Comment: I used `SHOW PROCESSLIST` but there are only 3 process, 2 are `sleep` and one in `Query`

Comment: Probably a good idea to check the [Slow Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html). Please add the DDL for your tables and the EXPLAIN output for the two sample queries provided.

Comment: SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; will likely provide more useful data for analysis.  Please post TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE order; B) SHOW CREATE TABLE delivery; and C) SHOW CREATE TABLE transport; as well as D) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "order"; E) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "delivery"; and F) SJPW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "transport"; for Query 1 analysis.